# Proper classes subnumerous to $V$ in a model of a Morse-Kelley related theory

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory

Let $\mathsf{MK^-}$ be the theory "$\mathsf{MK}-\text{Foundation}-\text{Limitation of size}-\text{Union}+\text{Subsets}$", where $\mathsf{MK}$ is Morse-Kelley set theory with axioms mentioned in:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse%E2%80%93Kelley_set_theory

Of course axioms of pairing and union and one direction of axiom of limitation of size are known to be redundant with this specific formulation of $\mathsf{MK}$.

Removal of axiom of limitation of size and putting the axiom of subsets (the axiom asserting that every subclass of a set is a set) instead of it would make it possible for some classes to be equinumerous to sets and yet not being sets, since it is known that
the axiom of subsets does not imply the assertion that every class that is equinumerous to a set is a set. So is it possible to have a model $M$ of $\mathsf{MK^-}$ such that we have all of the followings?

$M \vdash \exists P (\text {$P$ is a proper class} \wedge P < V)$
$M \vdash \forall P (\text{$P$ is a proper class} \wedge P < V \implies \exists x\in V (\text{$P$ is  equinumerous to x}))$

where "<" denotes "strict subnumerousity" defined in the customary manner; and $V$ is the class of all sets. Given that, it is clear that $M$ cannot satisfy closure of replacement over sets. The general context of this question is about size of proper classes and to what extent that can be shared with size of sets in absence of Replacement and global choice.

Also related to this is the following question:

If the above is possible then can we add the following:

$M \vdash \forall P (\text{$P$ is a proper class} \wedge P < V \implies \exists x \in V (x=\{\{y\}| y \in P\}))$

The special context of those questions raised when I was investigating an alternative to the axiom of limitation of size of $\mathsf{MK}$. A version that I've lately posted to FOM thread is referred to by the following link:

http://www.cs.nyu.edu/pipermail/fom/2016-September/020073.html

This version proves all axioms of Empty set, Pairing, Power, Separation (subsets), Replacement, Limitation of size, Global choice and Set union, so it is more powerful than the usual limitation of size axiom.

I've been trying to further simplify this axiom to the following:

$\forall x (x \in V \iff U(x) < V)$

However I couldn't prove Replacement nor union, so I was left with the above
situation (i.e., theory $\mathsf{MK^-}$); so if the possibilities that I've asked about specifically above were inconsistent then this would mean that this axiom can be simplified to the above version.

Comment: Could you clarify the question? Any model of KM itself has a bijection of V with Ord by the global choice axiom, and so any class that is strictly smaller than V is in fact bijective with an ordinal and hence is a set. So the property seems to be true (vacuously) in any model of KM, without needing to remove any axioms at all.

Comment: The theory I'm speaking about is not MK, it is a weak fragment of MK in which the axiom of subsets replace the axiom of limitation of size, also you don't have the union axiom, this theory doesn't prove global choice, so some models of it does have proper classes that are strictly smaller than V, for example you can have a model in which Ord is strictly subnumerous to V. Can you have such a model in which all of such classes are of set size?

Comment: My point is that every model of KM itself is also a model of that weak fragment, since nothing in your theory prevents this. I guess you intended to ask for a model with some additional properties, such as not having global choice etc.?

Comment: I'm still a little confused about what you want. If there is a proper class that is smaller than $V$, then by the meaning of "proper" class, it is not a set.

Comment: Yes the additional property I've added it to the question, that the model must have a proper class that is strictly subnumerous to V, so given that condition non of the models of the traditional version of KM that proves global choice is a model that I'm asking about. As regards your last question, I'm asking about the 'size' of a proper class and not its set-hood, yes a proper class is not a set, but it can be equi-numerous to a set? you don't have Replacement axiomatized here! the question is if that can be true of all proper classes that are strictly subnumerous to V.

Comment: to avoid confusion rising from the last line in my latest comment, I meant .. the question is if that is "possible" for all such proper classes, I meant if it is consistent to have that.

Comment: Could you state clearly the axioms that are in your theory, rather than which are not? There are several different equivalent formulations of Kelley-Morse, and some of them, for example, do not use the so-called Limitation of size axiom.

Comment: In general, the operation of removing an axiom from a theory is not well-defined up to logical equivalence. An interesting case is the removal of the power set axiom from ZFC: http://jdh.hamkins.org/what-is-the-theory-zfc-without-power-set/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the following gives a positive answer to your first question, modulo large cardinals:

Let $\kappa$ be measurable, and consider a [Prikry-generic](http://blog.assafrinot.com/?p=2156) extension of the universe $V[G]$. Look at $\mathcal{M}=(V_{\kappa+1})^{V[G]}$. We can view this as a model of $MK^-$ by taking the proper classes to be exactly those elements of $\mathcal{M}$ of rank $\kappa$. In particular, the generic $G$ - which is a cofinal map from $\omega$ to $\kappa$ - is a "proper class" in the sense of $\mathcal{M}$, yet equinumerous with the $\mathcal{M}$-set $\omega$.

I strongly suspect that the measurable is unnecessary here - I'm just too lazy to think up the details for a ZFC-example (maybe something closer to Namba forcing?). The reason I'm using Prikry here is because Prikry forcing doesn't add any bounded-rank subsets of $\kappa$, which gives a fast (but probably unnecessary) proof that $\mathcal{M}$ is in fact a model of $MK^-$.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a typo in how you defined the proper classes? Also, wouldn't that work with the first worldly cardinal without the need for forcing?

Comment: I don't think we need to go that far just to answer the first two conditions. I'll post an answer to this effect in ZFC

Comment: @AsafKaragila Derp. Fixed. And yes, it would work with just a worldly (but I really like Prikry forcing :P).

Comment: Who doesn't? Prikry forcing is an epitome of awesomeness!

Answer (score 1):

An answer to the first question is: Take a model $\mathcal{M}$ of $\text{ZF +GCH}$, the stage $V_{w+w+1}$ of $\mathcal{M}$ will satisfy all axioms of $\text{MK}^-$ plus the first two conditions of the first question: the stage $V_{w+w}$ would interpret the class $V$ of all sets of $\text{MK}^-$, a set of $\text{MK}^-$ is intepreted as an element of $V_{w+w}$, while a proper class of $\text{MK}^-$ is a subset of $V_{w+w}$ that is not an element of $V_{w+w}$; now we have $|V_{w+w}|=\aleph_w$, and since the Generalized Continuum Hypothesis "$\text{GCH}$" is equivalent to $\beth_\alpha=\aleph_\alpha$ for every infinite ordinal $\alpha$, then every cardinality less than the cardinality of $V_{w+w}$ would be either $n$ or $\aleph_{w+n}$ for a natural $n$, all of which are cardinalities of elements of $V_{w+w}$, and thus cardinalities of sets, that a proper class exists that is strictly subnumerous to $V$ is witnessed by the set of all $V_i$ stages with $i<w+w$, since it is a subset of $V_{w+w}$ and it is not an element of $V_{w+w}$ and its cardinality is $\aleph_0 <\aleph_w$. The rest of axioms of $\text{MK}^-$ (Extensionality, Class comprehension axioms, Pairing, Power, Infinity and Subsets) are interpreted straightforwardly.

Answer (score -1):

The stage $(V_{w+w+1})^L$ would serve as a model of $MK^-$ as far as the first two conditions are concerned, but it would fail the third condition. Classes would be interpreted as elements of $(V_{w+w+1})^L$, Sets are elements of $(V_{w+w})^L$ and proper classes are elements of $(V_{w+w+1})^L$ that are not elements of $(V_{w+w})^L$. $(V_{w+w})^L$  interprets $V$. Clearly it is provable *within* $(V_{w+w+1})^L$ that for each $n=0,1,2,..,w$ we have $(V_{w+n})^L < (V_{w+n+1})^L$ where < is strict subnumerousity, since each $(V_{i+1})^L$ is the constructible power set of $(V_i)^L$ and $L$ is a model of $ZFC$, now the largest cardinality "as seen inside $(V_{w+w+1})^L$" is the cardinality of $(V_{w+w})^L$, and because $L$ satisfies the general continuum hypothesis then we can *define* cardinality within $(V_{w+w+1})^L$ as:

$|x|=y \iff \exists F (F:y\to x \wedge \text{F is a bijection})\wedge (\text {y is a finite von Neumann} \lor \exists i (\text {i is infinite} \wedge y=V_i^L))$.

In English the cardinality of a set $x$ is the finite von Neumann ordinal that is equinumerous with $x$ or the infinite stage of the $(V_{w+w+1})^L$ that is equinumerous with $x$. So we *define* $\aleph_n$ as $(V_{w+n})^L$ for each $n=0,1,2,3,...,w$.

Now because $L$ satisfies the Generalized Continuum Hypothesis so it is provable within $L$ that all cardinals strictly smaller than $\aleph_w$ are either $n$ or $\aleph_n$ for some natural $n$ and each one of those is the cardinality of some element of $(V_{w+w})^L$ and each one of those is itself an element of $(V_{w+w})^L$. The set of all $V_i^L$ stages in $(V_{w+w})^L$ is a proper class of cardinality $\aleph_0$ which is strictly smaller than $\aleph_w$, and every proper class that is provable within $(V_{w+w+1})^L$ to be strictly smaller than $\aleph_w$ would be provable within $(V_{w+w+1})^L$ to be of cardinality $n$ or of cardinality $\aleph_n$ for a natural $n$, and so equinumerous to a set. So $(V_{w+w+1})^L$ satisfies $MK^-$ plus the first two conditions. However the third condition cannot be met since the set of all singletons of elements of any proper class would be a proper class too. And so this remains a partial answer.

The same argument would hold in any model of $ZF+GCH$, the stage $V_{w+w+1}$ of the cumulative hierarchy of that model would be a model that satisfies all axioms of $MK^-$ plus the first two conditions of the question. However it still fails the third condition. So it is also a partial answer.

Comment: (1) $2\omega=\omega$, you probably mean $\omega2$; (2) $L_{\omega2+1}$ is countable, it knows about no infinite cardinal except $\omega$ itself.

Comment: $2w > w$ where > is for ordinal greater than (not cardinal greater than), and definitely $L_{2w}$ is much bigger than $L_w$, the later is nothing but the set of all constructible hereditarily finite sets, while the fomrer is the union of all naturally indexed iterative constructible powers of the later. The cardinality of $L_w$ is $\aleph_0$, the cardinality of $L_{w+n}$ is $\aleph_n$, and that of $L_{2w}$ is $\aleph_w$

Comment: No. $2\omega=\omega$ and $\omega+\omega=\omega2$, the latter of which is indeed greater than $\omega$. Secondly, there are only countably many formulas in the language of set theory, and it follows that for an infinite $\alpha$, $|\alpha|=|L_\alpha|$. Unless your $2w$ is some uncountable ordinal, you're just wrong. I'm not saying that your idea cannot work, just that the way you present it contains several mistakes.

Comment: (I see now that someone downvoted your answer. It wasn't me.)

Comment: I think there is a confusion here, I'll edit my answer as to avoid this confusion. There is nothing to do with the number of formulas here, we are just taking different stages of Godel's constructible universe $L$.

Comment: The number of formulas is relevant in that the definition of the stages of L involves taking definable subsets of the previous stages. Asaf is perfectly right, $|L_\alpha|=|\alpha|$ for infinite ordinals $\alpha$, and standard ordinal multiplication makes $2\cdot\omega=\omega$ (the well order you get by putting $\omega$ many pairs after each other is still $\omega$).

Comment: I believe you are confusing $L_\alpha $ with $(V_\alpha)^L $; the $\alpha $th level of the $L $ hierarchy is **vastly** smaller in general than what $L $ thinks is the $\alpha $th level of the cumulative hierarchy. In particular, your first-paragraph sentence beginning "clearly it is provable" is completely false as written.

Comment: I've corrected my answer, I also clarified what is meant by having higher cardinalities, it is as seen within the model.  Of course the number of formulas is countable. I hope that helps.

Comment: @zuhair see my comment, the answer is still incorrect.

Comment: Yes I'm speaking about what $L$ thinks, I'm not speaking external to $L$. I'm saying it is provable "within" $L$. This is different from what we are having externally , since externally $L_\alpha$ is countable, but "internally" I mean as how $L$ is seeing matters within, it is as I said.

Comment: I'm speaking about stages of the constructible universe $L$ of Godel as how it is seen *within* that model and not as how it is seen externally. $L$ is a model of ZFC, so it proves within it that the power set of x is strictly greater in cardinality than x, so each stage would be strictly larger than its predecessor. That's obvious.

Comment: I'm specifically using "within" to mean provability within the model and not how it externally appears.

Comment: @Zuhair I understand that, but your statements are still incorrect; you do not understand the construction of $L$. Remember that $L_{\alpha+1}$ is the definable powerset of $L_\alpha$; this **does not mean** that $L$ thinks that $L_{\alpha+1}=\mathcal{P}(L_\alpha)$! Indeed, that statement is *extremely false*. For example, the constructible reals $L\cap\mathbb{R}$ are **not** $L_{\omega+1}\cap\mathbb{R}$, but rather $L_{\omega_1}\cap\mathbb{R}$; indeed, for any $L$-countable $\alpha$ there is a real $r\in L$ with $r\not\in L_\alpha$. This is a standard fact about the constructible hierarchy.

Comment: (cont'd) I **strongly** suggest you consult a standard reference on the subject, e.g. Devlin's book. (And indeed it **is true** that $L$ knows that $L_\alpha$ is countable for every $L$-countable $\alpha$; see e.g. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48726/the-cardinality-of-l-alpha-in-l.) The $L$ hierarchy looks very different from the $V$ hierarchy, even as computed inside $L$. Here are the basic facts: there are three hierarchies you care about, $\{L_\alpha\}$, $\{V_\alpha\}$, and $\{(V_\alpha)^L\}$. All three have the same *height*: $M_\alpha\cap ON=\alpha$ for each choice of $M$.

Comment: However, their *widths* are different. If $V\not=L$, then $V_\alpha\supsetneq (V_\alpha)^L$ in general; but even if $V$ does equal $L$, we will always have $L_\alpha\subsetneq (V_\alpha)^L$ for many $\alpha$! (Equality will hold if $\alpha$ is an $L$-cardinal, but otherwise not.) Even inside $L$, the $L$-hierarchy (not the $V$-hierarchy relative to $L$!) is seen to be incredibly thin. Here's an easy way to see that the $L$-hierarchy has to be thin, even in $L$: show that every real in $L_{\omega+1}$ is *arithmetic*. But ZFC proves there are non-arithmetic reals . . .

Comment: I see! then I must correct my answer. I think that $ZF+GCH$ can interpret $MK^-$, since the stage $V_{w+w+1}$ can act as a model of $"MK^- + \text{the first two conditions of my question}"$ no need to go to the constructible universe, however it still fails the third condition.

Comment: @Noah, so according to how you are putting things it appears that I should have spoken in terms of the $V$-hierarchy relative to $L$. So when it is said that $L$ satisfies ZFC, then it is the $V$-hierarchy relative to $L$ that is meant.

Comment: @Zuhair Yes, that's right. (But note that it's not "according to how I'm putting things together" - this is just what those symbols actually mean!) Also, note that the $L$-hierarchy *does* match up with the $V$-hierarchy relative to $L$, *eventually*. Specifically, if $\kappa$ is an $L$-cardinal then $L_\kappa=(V_\kappa)^L$; in particular, this means that $\bigcup_{\alpha\in ON} L_\alpha=\bigcup_{\alpha\in ON} (V_\alpha^L)=L$. The discrepancy comes when we examine *individual* (non-$L$-cardinal) levels.

Comment: OK, I've edited the answer to that effect.

Comment: @NoahSchweber You're being too generous (in your comment of Sep. 22) about the agreement of the L and V-in-L hierarchies. Consider, for example,  the $L$-cardinal $\kappa=(\omega_1)^{(L)}$.  $L$ thinks $L_\kappa$ has cardinality $(\omega_1)^{(L)}$, whereas $L$ thinks $(V_\kappa)^{(L)}$ is way bigger, $(\beth_{\omega_1})^{(L)}$ to be precise. The $L$-hieracrchy won't match the $V$-in-$L$ hierarchy until you get to a fixed-point of the $\beth$ sequence in $L$.